# Apache Link subdomain to website and game server

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, proxy, domain, website

Hi i am trying to link my subdomain e.g mc.mywebsite.co.uk to both my gameserver and website.

I have managed to link it to my game server using virtualhost proxypass

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mc.mywebsite.co.uk.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    ServerName mc.mywebsite.co.uk
    ServerAlias mc.mywebsite.co.uk
    ProxyRequests Off

    #ProxyPass / http://localhost:25565/
    <Location />
            ProxyPreserveHost On
            ProxyPass http://mywebsite.co.uk:25565/
            ProxyPassReverse http://mywebsite.co.uk:25565/
    </Location>
  # Uncomment the line below if your site uses SSL.
 #SSLProxyEngine On
```

I can connect to the game server in this case minecraft via mc.mywebsite.co.uk

However when i enter mc.mywebsite.co.uk into my web browser i get the following error

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.

Reason: Error reading from remote server

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at mc.mywebsite.co.uk Port 80
```

I am still new to this so sorry if i missed anything out. Do you guys know what i am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: We have loads of Q&A about Apache proxys. Perhaps you should browse them https://serverfault.com/search?q=%5Bapache2.4%5D+proxypass, compare your config to the ones in the Q&A and see if we already have an answer that helps you.

Comment: Is port 25565 for your gaming server?

Comment: The error suggest the service running on port 25565 is not an HTTP server at all. What is it?

Comment: Hi yes 25565 is my gaming server. It is running a minecraft server. I noticed other sites managed to make e.g mc.mywebiste.co.uk work for both connecting to their website and game server. That is what i am trying to do. Do you know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure MineCraft doesn't use HTTP. The sites you are talking about must be using a custom module or other code of some sort. You cannot do this using ProxyPass and the core Apache httpd modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's likely happening is that you are giving minecraft the url `mc.mywebsite.co.uk`, which the DNS resolves to `YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:80`, so its connecting to the minecraft server through port 80, which connects through apache (or more then likely it's just telling the request where it needs to go) to `http://localhost:25565/`. You shouldn't be routing requests through apache at all unless your hosting multiple websites, just open up port 25565 on your firewall, and in minecraft connect to the server through mc.mywebsite.co.uk:25565 which the DNS will resolve to `YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:25565` which is the correct location of your mine craft server. Anyone who is trying to access your website will be doing so through a browser, which will target port 80 (or 443 if ssl) and connect through apache which is where you will host your sites.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html

or like do it this way i guess

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
Listen 420
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/html"
    ServerName mc.mywebsite.co.uk

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:420>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
ServerName mc.mywebsite.co.uk
ServerAlias mc.mywebsite.co.uk
ProxyRequests Off

 #ProxyPass / http://localhost:25565/
        <Location />
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass http://mywebsite.co.uk:420/
        ProxyPassReverse http://mywebsite.co.uk:420/
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

but do you kinda see what I mean? its just accepting the connection on port 420 and sending it to port 25565.

connect to minecraft with mc.mywebsite.co.uk:420
and connect to website at mc.mywebsite.co.uk